# How to serve a WordPress blog at /blog/ with Nginx?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

All my attempts to Google "host wordpress on subdirectory" seem to be about moving the Wordpress installation to a subdirectory while still serving it from `/`. I want to serve it at `/blog/`.

I have one docker image running Nginx and another serving Wordpress via php-fpm. I updated `siteurl` in the wp_options table to be http://example.com/blog and finally got the index page to show up, but all the related assets give a 403 error. I though it might have to do with a rewrite directive in my Nginx conf, so I tried removing `rewrite ^/blog/(.*) /$1  break;`, but that then caused `/blog` to return 404.

Here's the relevant portion of my Nginx conf:

```
location /blog/ {
    resolver ${RESOLVER_IP};
    set $wordpress_host "${WORDPRESS_SERVICE_HOST}";
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*) /$1  break;


    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /srv$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /srv;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

    fastcgi_param HTTP_X_REAL_IP $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST $http_host;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $real_scheme;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST $http_host;
    # requests gzipped content from php. gunzip is used for clients that
    # can't accept gzip.
    fastcgi_param HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING "gzip";
    fastcgi_param HTTP_X_PREFERRED_TYPE $preferred_type;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_503;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 64k;
    # specifies buffer used for HTTP headers, doesn't need to be large
    fastcgi_buffer_size 2k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    fastcgi_pass $wordpress_host:80;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    #echo '';


    add_header X-document_root $document_root;
    add_header X-fastcgi_script_name $fastcgi_script_name;
    add_header X-request_uri $request_uri;
    add_header X-document_uri $document_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you created a Directory called `blog` under your Web_Root and uploaded the entire Wordpress to this location plus make some minor changes to the the `wp_options` table in Your Database; You may not need to touch any Configuration Files at all. Navigating to http://domain.com/blog/ would serve the expected same output... (which are Wordpress Pages).

Comment: That worked, except now the CSS files are returning with a 200 status code but no file content. JS files are working fine though.

Comment: @SeánHayes You may have to make minor adjustments as well to your `functions.php` File. You may need to check your styles & scripts enqueueing functions to see that the `URI` checks out fine...especially if they were using relative paths...

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress should be working if you uploaded it fully, and changed **siteurl** AND **home** records as you need them.